# error: "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(Code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I need help here. I am trying to use core data to implement an app. But on line 52 -

```
myHood.setMyHoodImg(addHoodImg.image!))
```

I having an error each time a click the button to create a new hood. The error:

> "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(Code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)

Here is the code:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class CreateHoodVC: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var hooddesc: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var addHoodImgBtn: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var addHoodImg: UIImageView!

var imagePicker: UIImagePickerController!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePicker.delegate = self
    addHoodImg.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0
    addHoodImg.clipsToBounds  = true

}

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage, editingInfo: [String : AnyObject]?) {

    imagePicker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    addHoodImg.image = image
}

@IBAction func addImage(sender: AnyObject!){

    presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)

}


@IBAction func createHood(){

    if let hoodDescription = hooddesc.text where hoodDescription  != ""{

        let app = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        let  context  = app.managedObjectContext
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("MyHood", inManagedObjectContext: context)!
        let myHood = MyHood(entity: entity, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)

        myHood.myHoodDescription = hoodDescription
        myHood.setMyHoodImg(addHoodImg.image!)

        context.insertObject(myHood)

        do {

            try context.save()
        } catch {
            print("Could not save new Hood")
        }
    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's really simple:

if You write:

```
myHood.setMyHoodImg(addHoodImg.image!)
```

you are supposing addHoodImg.image DOES exist, but on first run, is NIL, if You did not choose an image.
so 2 ways:

1) simply write:

```
if let hoodDescription = hooddesc.text where hoodDescription  != "" , let img = addHoodImg.image {
```

2) disable button on start AND enable after choosing and image.

Hope this help.

ps I have a fully functional proto here with (reduced!) classes you use.

Comment: I have implemented the first option. But i am still getting error See the error here :"  , 2016-08-20 06:14:42.924 My-Hood[5076:250083] _BSMachError: (os/kern) invalid capability (20)
2016-08-20 06:14:42.928 My-Hood[5076:250083] _BSMachError: (os/kern) invalid name (15)?